# How do I calculate average of last 10 values from a row containing blanks

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to calculate golf handicaps for a league.  There are 30 weeks on the schedule, and only the most recent 10 scores are used to calculate the handicap.   The data looks like this:

[image: Sample Data]

I am using this formula to calculate handicaps: `=ROUND((AVERAGE(Q3:AD3)-54)*0.8,0)`

Currently I have to adjust the range for each player, each week to include only their last 10 scores. How can I improve this formula to do that for me?

Comment: How about, when you add a new column to the data, instead of inserting a new column before the formula by rightclick->insert, just copy the column containing the handicap formula to the next column across. This will automatically change your formula to use the "next" last 10. (e.g. if you copy the formula by one column it will become =ROUND((AVERAGE(R3:AE3)-52)*0.8,0) ). I would recommend that you change how your data is laid out though. You'll quickly run out of columns!! Have you considered having players as columns and weeks as rows? There are far more rows than columns in Excel

Comment: Actually, I have over two-hundred players, more than columns so far. But I agree that the data is getting unmanageable after several years.  I am thinking of putting each year in a spreadsheet of its own, then using access or another db program to query for the data I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a more complex formula to consider last 10 cells with number:

`=ROUND((AVERAGE(OFFSET(B2,0,LARGE(IF(B2:W2>0,COLUMN(B2:W2),""),10)-COLUMN(B2),1,COLUMN(W2)+1-LARGE(IF(B2:W2>0,COLUMN(B2:W2),""),10)))-54)*0.8,0)`

where:

- `LARGE(IF(B2:W2>0,COLUMN(B2:W2),""),10)` gets the column number of the first number from the 10
- `OFFSET(B2,0,LARGE(...)-COLUMN(B2),1,COLUMN(W2)+1-LARGE(...),10)))` creates a reference to the range containing the 10 numbers
- `=ROUND((AVERAGE(OFFSET(...)-54)*0.8,0)` is the calculation according to your original formula

This is an array formula, so after inserting you need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

The formula will be automatically updated if you insert / delete columns to / from after first column referenced and before last column referenced.

[image]

Comment: This is excellent!  Exactly what I was looking for!  I new I need to use an array formula, but was never able to get it to work. THANK YOU!!!